# Find the equation of the circle touching the line $(x-2)\cos\theta+(y-2)\sin\theta=1$ for all values of $\theta$

Tags: trigonometry, contest-math, circles, coordinate-systems, tangent-line

> Find the equation of the circle touching the line $(x-2)\cos\theta+(y-2)\sin\theta=1$ for all values of $\theta$

The answer is given on [toppr website](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/the-line-x2cos-theta-y2sin-theta-1-touches-a-circle/).

It says, $(x-2)\cos\theta+(y-2)\sin\theta=\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta$, then comparing coefficients, it says,

$x-2=\cos\theta, y-2=\sin\theta$

I am not sure about this step. Do you think this step is valid?

Another answer exists on [sarthaks website](https://www.sarthaks.com/485338/show-that-the-line-x-2-cos-y-2-sin-1-touches-a-circle-for-all-values-of-find-the-circle).

It says equation of tangent to the circle $(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=a^2$ at $(x_1,y_2)$ is

$(x-h)x_1+(y-k)y_1=a^2$

Is this valid? I am not sure about this.

Comment: https://baijiahao.baidu.com/s?id=1734599640446824531&wfr=spider&for=pc is helpful for understanding the sarthaks's answer.

Comment: @youthdoo for $x^2+y^2=a^2$, I can understand the tangent is $xx_1+yy_1=a^2$ at the point of contact $(x_1, y_1)$. But I don't know what sarthaks website has done there. Do you think their formula is valid?

Comment: Their solution is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler and correct (verified by GeoGebra) solution.

The circle center is $(m,n)$, then its distance to the line must be constant as $\theta$ varies. If we write the line's equation as
$$x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta-2\cos\theta-2\sin\theta-1=0,$$
apply the distance formula to have
$$d=\frac{|m\cos\theta+n\sin\theta-2\cos\theta-2\sin\theta-1|}{\sqrt{\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta}}.$$
The denominator is $\sqrt1=1$, and the numerator is can be written as
$$\left|\sqrt{(m-2)^2+(n-2)^2}\sin(\theta+\varphi)-1\right|.$$
For it to be constant, $\sqrt{(m-2)^2+(n-2)^2}=0$, so $m=n=2$, and so $d=1$.

Our circle is therefore $\odot((2,2),1)$, equation
$$(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=1.$$

Comment: That's like my solution. +1

Comment: Hi, I have edited the title

Comment: @aarbee I've corrected the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I thought of another solution. Let us find the family of tangent lines of the circle
$$C: (x-m)^2+(y-n)^2=r^2.\tag1$$
Let $P=(m+r\cos\theta,n+r\sin\theta)\in C$ where $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$ is the family parameter. Then the slope of the tangent line at $P$ is $y'=\left.-\frac{x-m}{y-n}\right\rvert_P=-\cot\theta$. Hence, the tangent line at point P is
$$(x-m)\cos\theta+(y-n)\sin\theta=r.\tag2$$
Check! So, [the envelope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of the family $(2)$ is the circle $(1)$.

Therefore, the envelope of the family $(x-1)\cos\theta+(y-1)\sin\theta=1$ is $(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2=1$.

Comment: $m$ is usually used to denote slope. But, I started with youthdoo's circle so I can't use $m$ for slope. I skipped the derivation of the tangent line.

Comment: Actually in China usually $k$ is the slope.

Comment: That's a wonderful answer, thanks

Comment: Hi, I have edited the title

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the family of lines is always at a distance $1$ from $(2,2)$.

Hence this family is tangent to $(x-2)^2+(y-2)^2=1$

Comment: Try $\theta=\pi$ or something...?

Comment: Nice approach..